# Flutter / converting TextEdittingController text to integer

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to convert my text from TextFormField to an integer for example i insert '3' as string but i need to convert it to Int
here is my code
just focus on duration variable thats what i want it to be as int

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:social_sharing/LifeStyle_Health_Gym/models/Home%20model/AddPlan/PlanQsModel.dart';
import '../../../../Social_Sharing/shared/styles/icon_broken.dart';
import '../../../layout/cubit/cubit.dart';
import '../../../layout/cubit/states.dart';
import 'PlanDetailsScreen.dart';

class PlanQScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<PlanQScreen> createState() => _PlanQScreenState();
}

class _PlanQScreenState extends State<PlanQScreen> {

  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var planName = TextEditingController();
  var description = TextEditingController();
  var duration = TextEditingController();
  int? week = int.tryParse(duration); // Error here under duration
  dynamic goal = 'Muscle Building';
  List goalList =['Muscle Building','Fat Loss','Keep Fit'];
  dynamic levelChoose ='Beginner';
  List levelList =['Beginner','Expert','SuperMan'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<LifeStyleCubit,LifeStates>(
      listener: (context,state){},
      builder: (context,state)
      {
        PlanQsModel? model = PlanQsModel(
            planName: planName.text,
            description: description.text,
            duration: duration.text,
            goal: goal,
            level: levelChoose
        );
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: ()
              {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },icon: Icon(IconBroken.Arrow___Left_2),
            ),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('Plan Name*',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: planName,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'fill the information';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'type here',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text('Description',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: description,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'fill the information';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Plan Description',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text('Duration(Weeks)*',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: duration,
                      keyboardType:TextInputType.number,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'fill the information';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'type here',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text('Goal',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    DropdownButtonFormField(
                      value: goal,
                      items: goalList
                          .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: item,
                        child: Text(item),
                      )).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState(() {
                          goal = value ;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text('Level*',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    DropdownButtonFormField(
                      value: levelChoose,
                      items: levelList
                        .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: item,
                        child: Text(item),
                      )).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState(() {
                          levelChoose = value ;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 40,),
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 160,

                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          color: Colors.orange.shade900,
                        ),
                        child: MaterialButton(onPressed: ()
                        {
                          if(formKey.currentState!.validate())
                          {
                            LifeStyleCubit.get(context).createPlanQAnswers(
                                planName: planName.text,
                                description: description.text,
                                duration: duration.text,
                                goal: goal,
                                level: levelChoose
                            );
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context)=>PlanDetailsScreen(model)));
                          }
                        },
                          child: Text('ADD PLAN',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 17),),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

i tried to use another variable to convert my duration variable to int as follow

int week = int.tryParse(duration); but still not working

Comment: I cant find `int week = int.tryParse(duration);` on your snippet

Comment: i deleted this statement because it gives me error under duration 
int? week = int.tryParse(duration); 

error says :  Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'duration'.
  int? week = int.tryParse(duration);

Comment: can you include that on question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do lazy initialization

```dart
var duration = TextEditingController();
  late int? week = int.tryParse(duration.text);
```

Or can assign value on initState.

```dart
  var duration = TextEditingController();
  int? week;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    week = week = int.tryParse(duration.text);
  }
```

Comment: It will fix `Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to...`

Answer (score 1):

convert a string to an integer

```
String myString = "123";
int myInt = int.parse(myString);
print(myInt); // Output: 123
```

If you're not sure whether the string can be safely parsed as an integer, you can use the `int.tryParse()` method instead. The `int.tryParse()` method returns null if the string cannot be parsed as an integer, instead of throwing an exception.

```
String myString = "123";
int myInt = int.tryParse(myString);
if (myInt != null) {
  print(myInt); // Output: 123
} else {
  print("Invalid integer string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initialized `week` with a variable that's also initialized in the same class so the solution is to add `initState()` function and initialize `week` with `duration.toInt()` .

here is the solution copy and paste it and if you face any issue give me an update :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:social_sharing/LifeStyle_Health_Gym/models/Home%20model/AddPlan/PlanQsModel.dart';
import '../../../../Social_Sharing/shared/styles/icon_broken.dart';
import '../../../layout/cubit/cubit.dart';
import '../../../layout/cubit/states.dart';
import 'PlanDetailsScreen.dart';

class PlanQScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<PlanQScreen> createState() => _PlanQScreenState();
}

class _PlanQScreenState extends State<PlanQScreen> {

  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var planName = TextEditingController();
  var description = TextEditingController();
  var duration = TextEditingController();
  int week = 0; // Error here under duration
  dynamic goal = 'Muscle Building';
  List goalList =['Muscle Building','Fat Loss','Keep Fit'];
  dynamic levelChoose ='Beginner';
  List levelList =['Beginner','Expert','SuperMan'];


   @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    week = int.tryParse(duration);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<LifeStyleCubit,LifeStates>(
      listener: (context,state){},
      builder: (context,state)
      {
        PlanQsModel? model = PlanQsModel(
            planName: planName.text,
            description: description.text,
            duration: duration.text,
            goal: goal,
            level: levelChoose
        );
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: ()
              {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },icon: Icon(IconBroken.Arrow___Left_2),
            ),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('Plan Name*',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: planName,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'fill the information';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'type here',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text('Description',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: description,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'fill the information';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Plan Description',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text('Duration(Weeks)*',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: duration,
                      keyboardType:TextInputType.number,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'fill the information';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'type here',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text('Goal',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    DropdownButtonFormField(
                      value: goal,
                      items: goalList
                          .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: item,
                        child: Text(item),
                      )).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState(() {
                          goal = value ;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text('Level*',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    DropdownButtonFormField(
                      value: levelChoose,
                      items: levelList
                        .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: item,
                        child: Text(item),
                      )).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState(() {
                          levelChoose = value ;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 40,),
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 160,

                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          color: Colors.orange.shade900,
                        ),
                        child: MaterialButton(onPressed: ()
                        {
                          if(formKey.currentState!.validate())
                          {
                            LifeStyleCubit.get(context).createPlanQAnswers(
                                planName: planName.text,
                                description: description.text,
                                duration: duration.text,
                                goal: goal,
                                level: levelChoose
                            );
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context)=>PlanDetailsScreen(model)));
                          }
                        },
                          child: Text('ADD PLAN',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 17),),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```